# Define LDBL_MAX/MIN on C

Tags: c, double, long-double

I'm working with C, I have to do an exercise in which I have to print the value of `long double min` and `long double max`.

I used `float.h` as header, but these two macros (`LDBL_MIN/MAX`) give me the same value as if it was just a double.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and if I hover the mouse on `LDBL MIN` it says `#define LDBL_MIN DBL_MIN`. Is that why it prints `dbl_min` instead of `ldbl_min`?

How can I fix this problem?

```
printf("Type: Long Double Value: %lf Min: %e Max: %e Memory:%lu\n", 
    val10, LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX, longd_size);
```

It is a problem because my assignment requires two different values for `LDBL` and `DBL`.

Comment: Post the code/output rather than just _describe_ the code/output.  Why do you think the values of `LDBL_MAX/DBL_MAX` must differ or is a problem?

Comment: MSVC has `#define LDBL_MAX DBL_MAX` and similar for MIN. It does implement `long double` but it is the same as `double`.

Comment: The code is: printf("Type: Long Double  Value: %lf Min: %e Max: %e Memory:%lu\n", val10, LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX, longd_size); It is a problem because my assignment requires two different values for LDBL and DBL

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that **can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @Tsurupeta: Why are you trying to `printf` a supposedly `long double` value with `%e`? `%e` is for `float` (and `double`). For `long double` you need `%Le`.

Comment: @Tsurupeta Any more help needed with this post?

Answer (score 3):

C does not specify that `long double` must have a greater precision/range than `double`.

Even if the implementation treats them as different types, they may have the same implementation, range, precision, min value, max value, etc.

Concerning Visual Studio, [MS Long Double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx8xs15.aspx) helps.

To *fix* the problem, use another compiler that supports `long double` with a greater precision/range than `double`.  Perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org)?

Answer (score 2):

From [this reference on the lfoating point types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Real_floating_types):

> `long double` - extended precision floating point type. Matches IEEE-754 extended floating-point type if supported, otherwise matches some non-standard extended floating-point type as long as its precision is better than `double` and range is at least as good as `double`, **otherwise matches the type `double`**. Some x86 and x86_64 implementations use the 80-bit x87 floating point type.

Added emphasis is mine.

What the above quote says is that while a compliant C compiler must have the `long double` type, it doesn't really have to support it differently than `double`. Something which is probably the case with the Visual Studio C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Those macros are either broken, or long double is just an alias for double on your system. To test, set a long double to DBL_MAX, multiply by two, then subtract DBL_MAX from it. If the result is finite, then you have extra exponent space in the long double. If not, and long double is bigger than double, the extra bytes could just be padding, or you could have the same exponent space and more precision. So LDBL_MAX's genuine value will be just a smidgen over DBL_MAX.

The easiest way to generate the max is simply to look up the binary representation. However if you want to do it in portable C, you can probe it by repeated multiplications to get the magnitude, then fill out the mantissa by repeatedly adding descending powers of two until you run out of precision.

Comment: Just as `long int` does not have to be "better" than `int`, the same is true with `long double`. That does not make the implementation "broken".

Comment: That's what I said. Either long double is just an alias for double OR the macros are broken.